# Grouped Models Render Slowly in iOS (OpenGL ES 2.0)

Tags: ios, opengl-es

First, let me clarify what I mean by "grouped models."  I'm not actually sure what the standard terminology for this is.  In order to reduce the number of rendering calls, I am grouping multiple models into a single model, and rendering the whole thing with a single call to glDrawElements (using VBOs).  In my code, I call this a ModelGroup.  I use it for various things, but especially for large groups of geometrically simple objects (like buildings in a city, or particles).

The problem has recently surfaced where my ModelGroups are rendering very slowly.  I have isolated the slowdown to the actual call to glDrawElements by putting a timer around it.  For instance, my particles used to render ~10k particles (without instancing) at around 2ms or so.  I can't recall the exact number, but let's just say the rendering was definitely not the bottleneck as it currently is.  As of now, a single call to glDrawElements with 10k particles takes right about 256ms.  This performance is only marginally better than rendering the objects each with separate calls to glDrawElements.  So, there is clearly a massive burden on the GPU for some reason.

What has changed in my engine:
I recently updated XCode and changed from using EAGLView to using GLKViewController.  I changed nothing else in my code between these two very different states of performance.  I will say that, in order to migrate over to the use of the GLKViewController, I recreated my project entirely and added all of my source files in.  Then I rewrote my game loop to be updated by the GLKViewController's update function.  This was a very minor change, however.

Just to be completely clear on what my ModelGroup class does, I will post the function that compiles the added models into the display model which is rendered.

```
-(bool) compileDisplayModelWithNormals:(bool)updateNormals withTexcoords:(bool)updateTexcoords withColor:(bool)updateColor withElements:(bool)updateElements
{
    modelCompiled = YES;
    bool initd = displayModel->positions;

    // set properties
    if( !initd )
    {
        displayModel->primType = GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT;
        displayModel->elementType = GL_TRIANGLES;
        displayModel->positionType = GL_FLOAT;
        displayModel->texcoordType = GL_FLOAT;
        displayModel->colorType = GL_FLOAT;
        displayModel->normalType = GL_FLOAT;
        displayModel->positionSize = 3;
        displayModel->normalSize = 3;
        displayModel->texcoordSize = 2;
        displayModel->colorSize = 4;

        // initialize to zero
        displayModel->numVertices = 0;
        displayModel->numElements = 0;
        displayModel->positionArraySize = 0;
        displayModel->texcoordArraySize = 0;
        displayModel->normalArraySize  = 0;
        displayModel->elementArraySize = 0;
        displayModel->colorArraySize = 0;

        // sum the sizes
        for( NSObject<RenderedItem> *ri in items )
        {
            GLModel *model = ri.modelAsset.model.displayModel;
            displayModel->numVertices += model->numVertices;
            displayModel->numElements += model->numElements;
                displayModel->positionArraySize += model->positionArraySize;
            displayModel->texcoordArraySize += model->texcoordArraySize;
            displayModel->normalArraySize += model->normalArraySize;
            displayModel->elementArraySize += model->elementArraySize;
            displayModel->colorArraySize += model->colorArraySize;
        }
        displayModel->positions = (GLfloat *)malloc( displayModel->positionArraySize );
        displayModel->texcoords = (GLfloat *)malloc( displayModel->texcoordArraySize );
        displayModel->normals = (GLfloat *)malloc( displayModel->normalArraySize );
        displayModel->elements = (GLushort *)malloc( displayModel->elementArraySize );
        displayModel->colors = (GLfloat *)malloc( displayModel->colorArraySize );
    }

    // update the data
    int vertexOffset = 0;
    int elementOffset = 0;
    for( int j = 0; j < [items count]; j++ )
    {
        NSObject<RenderedItem> *ri = (GameItem *)[items objectAtIndex:j];
        GLModel *model = ri.modelAsset.model.displayModel;
        if( !ri.geometryUpdate )
        {
            vertexOffset += model->numVertices;
            continue;
        }
        // reset the update flag
        ri.geometryUpdate = NO;

        // get GameItem transform data
        rpVec3 pos = [ri getPosition];
        rpMat3 rot = [ri orientation];

        int NoV = model->numVertices;
        int NoE = model->numElements;
        for( int i = 0; i < NoV; i++ )
        {
            // positions
            rpVec3 r = rpVec3( model->positions, model->positionSize * i );

            // scale
            rpVec3 s = ri.scale;
            r.swizzleLocal( s );

            // rotate
            r = rot * r;

            // translate
            r.addLocal( pos );
            int start = model->positionSize * (vertexOffset + i);
            for( int k = 0; k < model->positionSize; k++ )
                displayModel->positions[start + k] = r[k];


            if( updateTexcoords )
            {
                // texcoords
                start = model->texcoordSize * (vertexOffset + i);
                if( model->texcoords )
                    for( int k = 0; k < model->texcoordSize; k++ )
                        displayModel->texcoords[start + k] = model->texcoords[model->texcoordSize * i + k];
            }
            if( updateNormals )
            {
                // normals (need to be rotated)
                if( model->normals )
                {
                    for( int k = 0; k < model->normalSize; k++ )
                    {
                        rpVec3 vn = rpVec3( model->normals, model->normalSize * i );
                        rpVec3 vnRot = rot * vn;
                        start = model->normalSize * (vertexOffset + i);
                        displayModel->normals[start + k] = vnRot[k];
                    }
                }
            }
            if( updateColor )
            {
                if( model->colors )
                {
                    start = model->colorSize * (vertexOffset + i);
                    displayModel->colors[start] = ri.color.r;
                    displayModel->colors[start + 1] = ri.color.g;
                    displayModel->colors[start + 2] = ri.color.b;
                    displayModel->colors[start + 3] = ri.color.a;
                }
            }
        }
        if( updateElements )
        {
            for( int i = 0; i < NoE; i++ )
            {
                // elements
                displayModel->elements[elementOffset + i] = model->elements[i] + vertexOffset;
            }
        }
        vertexOffset += NoV;
        elementOffset += NoE;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Just to be complete, here is how I render the particles.  Inside the particle field draw function:

```
glBindVertexArray( modelGroup.displayModel->modelID );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID );

// set shader program
if( changeShader ) glUseProgram( shader.programID );

[modelViewStack push];
mtxMultiply( modelViewProjectionMatrix.m, [projectionStack top].m, [modelViewStack top].m );

glUniformMatrix4fv( shader.modelViewProjectionMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, modelViewProjectionMatrix.m );
[DebugTimer check:@"particle main start"];
glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, modelGroup.displayModel->numElements, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 );
[DebugTimer check:@"particle main end"];

[modelViewStack pop];
```

The two statements that sandwich the glDrawElements statement are the timer I used to measure time between events.

Also, I just wanted to add that I have run on both the device and the iPad simulator 6.1 with the same result.  The simulator is slower at performing multiple draw calls, but both are equally slow at calling glDrawElements for a ModelGroup.  As far as hardware acceleration is concerned, I have checked to make sure that this performance hit isn't coming as some side effect of a lack of acceleration.  I rendered a model read in from a file which contained 1024 cubes (similar to a ModelGroup for a city) which rendered with no problem (no 20ms delay as with 1000 cubes in a ModelGroup).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that I have solved the mystery, in a manner of speaking.  It is, after all, still a mystery to me why this solves the problem.

I had been using my own custom enum values for these functions

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray
glVertexAttribPointer
```

instead of using the newly (as of iOS 5.0, I think) Apple-specified values that came as part of the GLKViewController class:

```
GLKVertexAttribPosition
GLKVertexAttribNormal
GLKVertexAttribTexcoord0
```

Having made this change yielded the kind of performance I expected when calling `glDrawElements`.  My model groups will now render on the order of 0.1 ms as they should, rather than ~20 ms.  As I said, I really do not understand exactly why this fixes anything, but it's a solution all the same.